# AES Encrypted data from python tcp server to nodejs client

Tags: python, node.js, encryption, aes

I am trying to encrypt/decrypt data from python to node.js using a tcp server.
The server send a encrypted message when a client connect to it.

It seem that i am sending well the data but it seems that the decoding of key is wrong.
I check several time my code but i did not find what is wrong with it.
I send key on purpose it just a test i will encrypt it with an other key later.

Here is my code :

**server.py**

```
import socketserver
import json
from base64 import b64encode,b64decode
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Random import get_random_bytes

class Handler_TCPServer(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
    data = "A random secret"
    
    key = get_random_bytes(32)

    cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CFB)
    ct_bytes = cipher.encrypt(data.encode())
    
    iv = b64encode(cipher.iv).decode('utf-8')
    ct = b64encode(ct_bytes).decode('utf-8')
    
    json_encode = json.dumps({'key':key.hex(),'iv':iv, 'ciphertext':ct},indent=2)
    
    self.request.sendall(json_encode.encode())
    
    json_decode = json.loads(json_encode)
    iv = b64decode(json_decode['iv'])
    ct = b64decode(json_decode['ciphertext'])

    cipher = AES.new(bytes.fromhex(json_decode['key']), AES.MODE_CFB, iv=iv)
    date_decrypted = cipher.decrypt(ct)

    print("Secret was: ", date_decrypted.decode())
    print(data.encode().hex())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    HOST, PORT = "localhost", 9000
    tcp_server = socketserver.TCPServer((HOST, PORT), Handler_TCPServer)
    tcp_server.serve_forever()
```

**client.js**

```
var net = require('net');
var crypto = require('crypto'); 

var HOST = 'localhost';
var PORT = 9000;

var client = new net.Socket();
var buff = []

function decrypt(json) { 
    let iv = Buffer.from(json.iv,'base64');
    let encryptedText = Buffer.from(json.ciphertext,'base64'); 
    let key =  Buffer.from(json.key,'hex')
    
    let decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-cfb',key, iv); 
    decrypted = Buffer.concat([decipher.update(encryptedText), decipher.final()]); 
    return decrypted.toString(); 
} 
   

client.on('data', function(data) {    
    console.log('Client received: ');
    buff.push(data)    
});

client.on('end', function(data) {    
    let concat   = Buffer.concat(buff);
    let json_decode = JSON.parse(concat);
    let msg_decrypt = decrypt(json_decode)
});

client.connect(PORT, HOST, function() {
    console.log('Client connected to: ' + HOST + ':' + PORT); 
});

client.on('timeout',function(){
    console.log('timeout')
})

client.on('close', function() {
    console.log('Client closed');
});
 
client.on('error', function(err) {
    console.error('error',err);
});
```

Comment: In the Python code, CFB8 is used by default for [`MODE_CFB`](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/cipher/classic.html#cfb-mode). The corresponding counterpart in the NodeJS code is `aes-256-cfb8`, s. [`crypto.getCiphers()`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_getciphers). With this, the Python-encryption/NodeJS-decryption part works, at least on my machine.

Comment: Just change to aes-256-cfb8. It works, thanks.